# Almost all of bootstrap styling not working in IE8. Works fine in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a classic .asp site and am using bootstrap for styling. 
Everything is working fine in chrome and firefox, but almost all of the styling is missing in IE8.

I'm using bootstraps carousel and modal and none of them are looking like they should. The carousel is just rendered as a series of images and none of the back/forward buttons are working.

The modal isn't styled at all, and is just inserted on the page as a "box" with a border" (no backdrop, rounded corners or anything).

I've tried a few more of the bootstrap library styles, such as tables and buttons and nothing looks like it should. 
I know that the bootstrap.css gets included as some of the styling works (e.g button colors).
The bootstrap js works fine.

Is there anything additionally that I need to add to my html docs (doc types or what not) to make bootstrap work as it should in IE?

I'm using bootstrap v2.2.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do realize that IE8 doesn't support very many of the newer CSS properties like `border-radius` (rounded corners) or `linear-gradient`, right?

Comment: Have you brought up the Bootstrap site and gone through their docs and demos in IE8 to see what does and doesn't work? A lot of what Bootstrap does stylistically (CSS3) isn't natively supported by IE7/8 (9 is better), whereas Firefox and Webkit (Safari/Chrome) support CSS3 rather well. See http://caniuse.com for more information. Oh, and provide a http://jsfiddle.net demo and check your `doctype`. What is it?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Yes, I'm aware that IE8 doesn't support many newer css properties, but this i far beyond that. I checked the bootstrap sites and the main items I'm using at the moment (modal and carousel) looks fine, excepts transitions and things like border-radius, like you mention cimmanon. On my site, these are completely unstyled.

Comment: My doctype is set to <!DOCTYPE html> . I can't really provide a fiddle, as this is another site i'm building some minor components into, hence the fiddle wouldn't really show what is going on.

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out. Wow this is really stupid. Apparently I was running IE in quirks mode.. This is what happens when you let a mac guy mess around in windows. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. Wow this is really stupid. Apparently I was running IE in quirks mode.. This is what happens when you let a mac guy mess around in windows. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 11):

There's some HTML5 shim excerpt (see below) necessary to support the HTML5 doctype in IE8 and lower. Did you check if it's still in the pages you built?

```
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes, I included this script. I've got it working now. Turns out I had set IE to quirks mode. Thanks anyway!